# GQL SELECT by date

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this model:

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    url = db.URLProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    image = db.URLProperty()
    weight = db.IntegerProperty()
    category = db.StringProperty()
    desc = db.TextProperty()
```

I have lots of entries each day, how do I SELECT only today's entries by using GGL ?
since query like this does not return any results ( but I know that there is results ):

```
SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE category = 'news' and date = '2012-03-12' ORDER BY weight DESC
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not saved as a string, but as a datetime like object.

> The right-hand side of a comparison can be one of the following:
>
> - a datetime, date, or time literal, with either numeric values or a
>     string representation, in the following forms:
>
>   DATETIME(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
>     DATETIME('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
>     DATE(year, month, day)
>     DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')
>     TIME(hour, minute, second)
>     TIME('HH:MM:SS')

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

So in your example, use either of these.

```
date = DATE('2012-03-12')
date = DATE(2012,03,12)
```

For datetime the time is by default set to 00:00, so equality comparison will fail therefore you must use > to compare

```
SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE date > DATETIME(yyyy,mm,dd)
```

Comment: @LukasŠalkauskas: probably because you save as datetime, but query as date, which assumes 00:00:00.000000 for time, and no entry matches that. try >= to test it, or save as date.

Comment: Right, your model says DateTimeProperty so you must use the DATETIME function in GQL.

Comment: Do these work with BigQuery - we are getting an error "DATE function not recognized"?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone need to looking for a datetime, it works for me in GQL:

```
select * from tableName where recordDate >= DATETIME('2018-10-07T00:56:36z')
```

I hope it help to anyone

Comment: Do you know how I can get data that is 45 days old?

Comment: tell me if this post can help you my friend:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599557/how-to-get-last-7-days-data-from-current-datetime-to-last-7-days-in-sql-server