# How to get last 7 days data from current datetime to last 7 days in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pentaho, pentaho-cde

Hi I am loading table A data from sql server to mysql using pentaho
when loading data i need to get only last 7 days data from sql server A table to mysql
In sql server createddate column data type is like datetime AND
In mysql created_on column datatype is timestamp

Here I used below query but i am getting only 5 days data
Please help me in this issue

```
select id,    
NewsHeadline as news_headline,    
NewsText as news_text,    
state,    
CreatedDate as created_on      
from News    
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()
order by createddate DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure you have 7 days data?

Comment: yes i am sure i have 7 days data

Comment: There has to be data for every single day in the past 7 days

Comment: i have dec 19th -1 row data,18th -2 rows,17th -3 rows,16th -3 rows,15th -3 rows,12th -2 rows, 11th -4 rows,9th -1 row,8th -1 row

Answer (score 65):

Try something like:

```
 SELECT id, NewsHeadline as news_headline, NewsText as news_text, state CreatedDate as created_on
 FROM News 
 WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Another way to do it to get the most recent 7 days, including the current date:

`[rest of query]... WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN (SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,-6, GETDATE()) AS DATE)) AND (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))`

Answer (score 11):

```
select id,    
NewsHeadline as news_headline,    
NewsText as news_text,    
state,    
CreatedDate as created_on    
from News    
WHERE CreatedDate>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Also make sure you have past 7 days data in the table News

Comment: i have past data from 2010 to 2014 dec 19th

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you have data for every single day for the past seven days. Days for which no data exist, will obviously not show up.

Try this and validate that you have data for EACH day for the past 7 days

```
SELECT DISTINCT CreatedDate
FROM News 
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
ORDER BY CreatedDate
```

EDIT - Copied from your comment

> i have dec 19th -1 row data,18th -2 rows,17th -3 rows,16th -3
>   rows,15th -3 rows,12th -2 rows, 11th -4 rows,9th -1 row,8th -1 row

You don't have data for all days. That is your problem and not the query. If you execute the query today - 22nd - you will only get data for 19th, 18th,17th,16th and 15th. You have no data for 20th, 21st and 22nd.

EDIT - To get data for the last 7 days, where data is available you can try

```
select id,    
NewsHeadline as news_headline,    
NewsText as news_text,    
state,    
CreatedDate as created_on      
from News    
WHERE CreatedDate IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 CreatedDate from News
order by createddate DESC)
```

Comment: i have dec 19th -1 row data,18th -2 rows,17th -3 rows,16th -3 rows,15th -3 rows,12th -2 rows, 11th -4 rows,9th -1 row,8th -1 row

Comment: In this situation by leaving 14th and 13th data if i want get 12th,11th,9th,8th data how can i do that help me

Comment: Thanks For above query it is giving last 7 records not giving last 7 days records

Answer (score 7):

DATEADD and GETDATE functions might not work in MySQL database. so if you are working with MySQL database, then the following command may help you.

```
select id, NewsHeadline as news_headline,    
NewsText as news_text,    
state, CreatedDate as created_on    
from News    
WHERE CreatedDate>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY);
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 3):

To pull data for the last 3 days, not the current date :

```
date(timestamp) >= curdate() - 3
AND date(timestamp) < curdate()
```

Example:

```
SELECT *

FROM user_login
WHERE age > 18
AND date(timestamp) >= curdate() - 3
AND date(timestamp) < curdate()

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: If someone asked have you cheated on your diet in the *last 7 days*, and you had this morning then it would count. I personally don't feel LAST X DAYS should exclude today. Use *Past* instead of *Last*. I can occasionally see merit in feeling the other way, for example: "I spent the last few years poor" (after winning the lottery *today*).

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me!!**

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where `created_at` BETWEEN CURDATE()-7 AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **DATEADD** function in your where clause like

```
select ...... where Createdate >= DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CreatedDate > (select dateadd(WEEK, -1, getdate()))
```

you can search CreatedDate in future week too by reversing the sign of 1 (change -1 to 1):

```
CreatedDate > (select dateadd(WEEK, 1, getdate()))
```

In place of 'WEEK' you can use 'DAY', 'MONTH' or 'YEAR' as per your need.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Pentaho DI, you can use "**Modified JavaScript**" Step and write the below function:

```
dateAdd(d1, "d", -7);  // d1 is the current date and "d" is the date identifier
```

Check the image below: *[Assuming current date is : 22 December 2014]*

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help,

```
select id,    
NewsHeadline as news_headline,    
NewsText as news_text,    
state,    
CreatedDate as created_on      
from News    
WHERE CreatedDate >= cast(dateadd(day, -7, GETDATE()) as date)
and CreatedDate < cast(GETDATE()+1 as date) order by CreatedDate desc
```