# how to select row in mysql on basis of 3 different column

Tags: mysql

I have a table consisting reports, I want to select data of last 7 day's. So in below image you can see 3 column day's month year.

What is the sql query to select last 7 day's.

[image]

Comment: Last 7 days with regard to _which_ date?  Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599557/how-to-get-last-7-days-data-from-current-datetime-to-last-7-days-in-sql-server

Comment: why store your dates like that and not simply a date type in one column?

Comment: @ankit-pundir you should store date in single column

Comment: i want to store data in single column but due to performance i try store separately. i have possible 1 million rows in one month and grow up every month. so campare string is slower than compare numbers. that's why facebook store their user id in number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,

```
    SELECT 
            *    
    FROM 
            < your_table > 
    WHERE 
            STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`day`, ',', `month`, ',' ,`year`), '%e,%m,%y') 
            BETWEEN 
            DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE();
```

If you want to use latest date from the same table,

try fetch max date separately with query ,

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`day`, ',', `month`, ',' ,`year`), '%e,%m,%y')) AS maxdat FROM < your_table >
```

store it, and use it in the main query in-place of CURDATE(),

or,

you can use the same query as a sub-query if you don't have any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

On which basis you want last 7 days entry.

Try this to find date before 7 days:

```
WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

OR

```
WHERE t.date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Or you can go through [Date_doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate-add) documentation.

Comment: last 7 day's according to this data. not last 7 entries.

Comment: use that above commands, even you will not get perfect entries then go through that Date document