# How can I fetch rows from a table that have been created or modified in the last two days?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]  DATETIME         DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] DATETIME         DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

What I need to do is a simple select * but I am not sure how to enter in the select where clause criteria.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What about the `WHERE` clause do you not understand?

Comment: Please clarify "in last two days" as either "any time on a datetime from the date two days ago" OR "48 hours from the current time" this varies the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last 7 days data from current datetime to last 7 days in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599557/how-to-get-last-7-days-data-from-current-datetime-to-last-7-days-in-sql-server) - note just change the query to 2 instead of 7 in that question perhaps?  Another possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you define what "2 days ago" is:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())
```

Note that this includes the time component.

Since you always set the `ModifiedDate` with a `DEFAULT` value, we only need to check that column:

```
WHERE ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selection:

```
SELECT *
FROM Phrase
WHERE createddate >= dateadd(day,-2,getdate())
```