# How to select last seven day's dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select last seven day's dates in the select statement as current date is `2018-07-12`

Expected result :

> Last_Seven_Days_Dates
>   2018-07-06
>   2018-07-07
>   2018-07-08
>   2018-07-09
>   2018-07-10
>   2018-07-11
>   2018-07-12

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599557/how-to-get-last-7-days-data-from-current-datetime-to-last-7-days-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last 7 days data from current datetime to last 7 days in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599557/how-to-get-last-7-days-data-from-current-datetime-to-last-7-days-in-sql-server)

Comment: I don't want to use that in any where condition just want a result as described in question and store it in temp table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your expected results listed in the question are exactly what you are looking for, this will do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
) AS the_table
```

results:

```
Last_Seven_Days_Dates
---------------------
2018-07-05
2018-07-06
2018-07-07
2018-07-08
2018-07-09
2018-07-10
2018-07-11
2018-07-12
```

Since you stated you'll want these in a temp table, I've updated the answer to make it a subquery, a little easier to join or do something with.

Additionally if you need it in a temporary table you could do this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTableName FROM (
    SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
    UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Last_Seven_Days_Dates
)
```

Comment: thanks I also searched for above query. is there any option?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question :)  What option are you looking for?

Comment: Instead of doing union any other option to get last seven days dates?

Comment: I suppose you could build a cursor or use a CTE but I think in the end you'll need to union the results.

Comment: I've updated the answer so it's a subquery now, so you could `JOIN` to it easily or put it into a temp table.

Comment: @sniperd I've added to an example of inserting to a temporary table to your answer and just changed the formatting.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following to generate date series

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()),
        @MaxDate DATE = GETDATE();

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a;
```

You can wrap it in a function and pass in MinDate and MaxDate if you ever need to make it reusable

Answer (score 3):

I would use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select cast(getdate() as date) as dte, 1 as cnt
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), cnt + 1
      from dates
      where cnt < 7
     )
select dte
from dates;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
DATEADD(DAY, -7, getDate()) < [date_field]
```

on your query

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where  date_field>=dateadd(day,-7,cast(getdate() as date)) and date_field<cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: I don't want to use that in any where condition just want a result as described in question and store it in temp table