# Using Pivot Table to Show Student Attendance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I m using SQL 'Pivot' to show Student Attendance on monthly basis but facing `Error Invalid column name 'DayValue'. Invalid column name 'Stu_Status'`.

M using following SQL Query

```
Select 
       StudentID, Stu_Status, DAY([AttandanceDate]) as [DayValue] 
  From tbl_Students_Attandance as studAttd
 PIVOT (Max([Stu_Status])
   FOR [DayValue] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],
       [10],  [11], [12], [13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],
       [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27], [28], [29],[30])
       ) AS Piviottable;
```

using below table Design

[SQL Table Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84M4l.png)

To achieve below result
[Required result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmaL1.png)

Comment: You are in the right direction, give some more effort, you can achieve your desired output in the same way.

Comment: It may work `FOR DAY([AttandanceDate]) IN (`

Comment: Please update your question adding tables in text format instead of images

Comment: What about Feb month? Will it work?

Comment: What about dynamic days as per current month?

Comment: have a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/q/51306478/7124761 
I used it for last seven days

Comment: Can you explain how do you want your day's like As per current month or from any  table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** There are few issues in your query so if it works then compare both queries and try to understand what you just missed

```
SELECT StudentID, [1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],
       [10],  [11], [12], [13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],
       [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27], [28], [29],[30], [31]
FROM(
    Select 
       StudentID, Stu_Status, DAY([AttandanceDate]) as [DayValue] 
  From tbl_Students_Attandance
) AS studAttd
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Stu_Status)
    FOR [DayValue] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],
       [10],  [11], [12], [13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],
       [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27], [28], [29],[30], [31])
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *conditional* aggregation instead :

```
select StudentID, max(case when day(AttandanceDate) = 1 then Stu_Status end) as [1],
       . . . 
from  tbl_Students_Attandance as studAttd
group by StudentID;
```

However, i suspect this will also require to mention `year()` to match current `year` & `month` attendance.

Comment: can u give me fiddle or some working example @Yogesh Sharma ?