# Getting all previous records of table by date MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

My table currently has 21000 records, it's daily updated and almost 300 entries are inserted. Now, what I want is to have a query which will fetch the counts of elements that my table had for the previous 10 days, so it returns:

> 26000

> 21300

> 21000

etc

Right now, I wrote this:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_task where `task_start_time` < '2020-12-01'"
```

And it returns 21000 but only for 1 day. I want by query to return records according to 10 days.

However, this does it for only 1 day.
edit : database flavor is mysql and date column is date not datetime

Comment: [See if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27599557/681929)

Comment: 'f you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: Edit your question and specify the kind of database engine you're using, including the version, so people can give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method may be aggregation and cumulative sums:

```
select date(task_start_time) as dte, count(*) as cnt_on_day,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by date(task_start_time)) as running_cnt
from tbl_task
group by dte
order by dte desc
limit 10;
```

This returns the last 10 days in the data.  You can easily adjust to more days if you like -- in fact all of them -- without much trouble.

Comment: thankyou. sorry to bother but can u tell me how can i now add a variable instead of just hard code 10. this is out of scope for this question i know but what would be its syntax

Comment: @SalmanAhmed . . . The syntax for `limit` explains what can be passed in:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` and date arithmetic.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM tbl_task
       WHERE task_start_time < current_date
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*)
       FROM tbl_task
       WHERE task_start_time < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
...
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*)
       FROM tbl_task
       WHERE task_start_time < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 9 DAY);
```

---

Edit:

You might also join a derived table that uses `FROM`-less `SELECT`s and `UNION ALL` to get the days to look back and then aggregate. This might be a little easier to construct dynamically. (But it may be slower I suspect.)

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM (SELECT 0 x
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 1
             ...
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 9)
            INNER JOIN tbl_task t
                       ON t.task_start_time < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL x.x DAY)
       GROUP BY x.x;
```

In MySQL version 8+ you can even use a recursive CTE to construct the table with the days.

```
WITH RECURSIVE x
AS
(
SELECT 0 x
UNION ALL
SELECT x + 1
       FROM x
       WHERE x + 1 < 10
)
SELECT count(*)
       FROM x
            INNER JOIN tbl_task t
                       ON t.task_start_time < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL x.x DAY)
       GROUP BY x.x;
```

Comment: but i want to make this dynamic so its upto user can filter number of days

Comment: @SalmanAhmed: That's not what you've asked. Please don't change the question and invalidate answers.

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to mention it in question, your answer is correct according to current requirements of question. i guess i can workaround this answer and use loops to make it dynamic but if theres a better solution please do tell

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm wrong, but could you not simple add a GROUP BY - statement? Like:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_task where `task_start_time` < '2020-12-01' GROUP 
BY task_start_time"
```

EDIT:
This should only work if task_start_time is a date, not if it is a datetime

EDIT2:
If it is a datetime you could use the date function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_task where `task_start_time` < '2020-12-01' GROUP 
BY DATE(task_start_time)
```

Comment: its returning records of that date only instead what i want is to get all records that exists in that table by that date

Comment: ok, could you please edit your question an add the type of db you are using (mysql, mariadb...) and the format the column task_start_time has. Is it a date or a datetime? @SalmanAhmed

Comment: edited : date is date not datetime and db is mysql

Comment: thank you, i think @o-jones has already provided a good example. i would have come up with something similar. You should consider his answer