# GQL error when formatting datetime query

Tags: google-app-engine, datetime, gql

I'm attempting to format a GQL query that pulls data between two dates.  I've referred to several existing StackOverflow threads ([GQL SELECT by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700579/gql-select-by-date) for example), and have tried following the formatting shown there, but for some reason when I test my query out it gives me an error.

Here is the query I'm attempting to use:

```
SELECT * FROM Packets WHERE timestamp > DATETIME(2017,12,23) AND timestamp < DATETIME(2017,12,29) LIMIT 10
```

It gives this error:

```
"GQL query error: Encountered "2017" at line 1, column 50. Was expecting one of: <SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING>, <DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING>"
```

I've tried enclosing the dates in strings, I've tried using the DATE object, every format I can think of gives me some sort of error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is right, the DATETIME method needs a single string parameter.

According to the GQL reference, to instanciate a DATETIME in a query the format must be 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSSSS+zz:ZZ':

> **DATETIME**  DATETIME() represents a timestamp.  must be
>   in the time format specified in RFC 3339 section 5.6. (However, the
>   second precision is limited to microseconds and leap seconds are
>   omitted.) This standard format is: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSSSS+zz:ZZ
>   ...

Your example working:

```
SELECT * FROM Packets WHERE timestamp > DATETIME('2013-09-20T09:30:20.00002-08:00') AND timestamp < DATETIME('2013-09-29T09:30:20.00002-08:00') LIMIT 10
```

You can check the complete article here :
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference

Comment: I tried this, being careful to set the date range to match entities I verified were in the datastore:

SELECT * FROM Packets WHERE timestamp > DATETIME('2017-04-03T09:30:20.00002-08:00') AND timestamp < DATETIME('2017-04-07T09:30:20.00002-08:00') LIMIT 10

And it still returned no queries.  Any idea why not?

Comment: Make sure that your 'timestamp' property is indexed. If it is not indexed, no results will return and also no error.

Comment: Yes, it's indexed.

Comment: Maybe the entities that match the query arent indexed? Entities of a type can be mixed (indexed/unindexed)

Comment: I can find them using "query by kind", which shouldn't be possible if they aren't indexed.

Comment: I figured it out, I think.  Typo in query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can do my query!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comment this problem.

With the answers of each one I can do a very easy (but almost impossible in GQL) Query.

Check this out, I hope it will help to someone:

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE recordDate >= DATETIME('2018-09-09T00:00:00.00000-03:00') 
AND recordDate <= DATETIME('2018-09-20T23:59:59.99999-03:00')
```

> **Where "2018-09-09T00:00:00.00000-03:00" is the full datetime value and
>   it means:**
>
> - **2018-09-09**  -> Date Indicator (YYYY-MM-DD in my case)
> - **T**           -> Indicator that the next values are Time values
> - **00:00:00.00000** -> Time Indicator (HH:mm:ss:[miliseconds])
> - **-03:00** -> Time Zone indicator (Chile in my case)

I really hope this post will be useful to anyone that have the same trouble with dates using GQL